# multiple call of gcry_md_write function

Tags: sha256

May be it 's not a question for information security stack exchange and if it's true excuse me for my mistake.

I want to understand how this code works:

```
char *s = "1";
char *s_2 = "2";

unsigned char *x;

gcry_md_hd_t h;
gcry_md_open(&h, GCRY_MD_SHA256, GCRY_MD_FLAG_SECURE); 

gcry_md_write(h, s, strlen(s)); 
gcry_md_write(h, s_2, strlen(s_2)); 
x = gcry_md_read(h, GCRY_MD_SHA256);
```

Well, i have two schemes and both of them don't work.

1. x = SHA256(SHA256("1") || SHA256("2")).

`SHA256("1") = 6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b;`

`SHA256("2") = d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35`

`SHA256(SHA256("1") || SHA256("2")) = 4295f72eeb1e3507b8461e240e3b8d18c1e7bd2f1122b11fc9ec40a65894031a`

2. x = SHA256(SHA256("1") || "2")

`x = a29972da68d930f3bd40fa9c150137c780cf55f4d7187335a9f4b9043736f02a`

But the result `x` (output from program) is

`6b51d431df5d7f141cbececcf79edf3dd861c3b4069f0b11661a3eefacbba918`

How does this code work??

Answer (score 1):

This code is simply doing:

SHA256("12") = 6b51d431df5d7f141cbececcf79edf3dd861c3b4069f0b11661a3eefacbba918

First of all, it is using libgcrypt, something you fail to mention, and whose documentation should point you in the right path.

> gcry_md_open(&h, GCRY_MD_SHA256, GCRY_MD_FLAG_SECURE);

Create a message digest context

> gcry_md_write(h, s, strlen(s));

Add "1" to the things you are hashing

> gcry_md_write(h, s_2, strlen(s_2));

Add "2" to the things you are hashing

> x = gcry_md_read(h, GCRY_MD_SHA256);

Obtain the hash output of what was provided, ie. "1" || "2" == "12"

Also note that those strlen() work there just because you are not hashing binary data, otherwise you would get the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not evaluating `SHA256(SHA256("1") || SHA256("2"))` as claimed. Instead the code is starting a SHA256 digest, putting "1" into the digest followed by "2" and then returning the result. This is the same as computing `SHA256("12")`.